# Heatmap looks like Scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap of latitude/longitude and the concentration of Enterococci bacteria. Here's the dataset:

[image]

This is my code for the heatmap:

```
bacteria.heatmap <- ggplot(data = bacteria_data, mapping = aes(x = Latitude,
                                                   y = Longitude,
                                                   fill = Enterococci..cfu.100ml.)) + geom_tile() + xlab(label = "Latitude")
bacteria.heatmap
```

This produces the following:

[image]

As seen, it looks more like a scatterplot than it is a heatmap. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: A heat map has a data point for every x,y combination. A 10x10 square needs 100 points accordingly to fill the whole plane, which is not the case in your example.

Comment: https://r-graph-gallery.com/79-levelplot-with-ggplot2.html